# My Pokemon Go maps won't load

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I downloaded Pokemon Go 10 days ago and I caught my starter pokemon. After that the application gave me the following error message:"GPS signal not found" and the map won't load, so I just stand in a blue screen.

Some of my friends have the "GPS signal not found" error message too and suggested I download GPS enhancing apps. At first the GPS enhancing apps didn't work, but after I deleted and reinstalled my Pokemon Go app it works normally. Now Pokemon Go still showing "GPS signal not found" with a blue screen instead of a map of the area I am in.

I've tried downloading the offline maps, but that just didn't work.

Comment: What device are you using to play? (Android phone, iPhone, etc), are you sure you've enabled the GPS features of your device?

Comment: "GPS enhancing app" sounds like snake oil. I wouldn't trust any app that claims to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Do not download any other application that involves GPS. For playing pokemon Go, you only need to download that app. Some third-party apps makes your Pokemon Go malfunction. I suggest reinstall to have a clean app after the GPS enhacing apps.

Also, the google maps offline option is not proved to work.

Comment: What do you mean not proved ... The game uses google API. The game just paints google maps with slightly more animated colors. If you go and download your city or whatever in google maps, to have it stored offline then when you go out and about and walk in the app it will NOT download the maps constantly but use the downloaded offline maps ...

Comment: if you dont have google maps, it works? yes it does. so having Google maps and offline maps downloaded is not proved to have better performance in loading or battery usage

Comment: IF you don't have maps it will just load the map on the go. If you have maps downloaded it will NOT download anything, thats how the services work that take care of the maps in the game...

Comment: you don't happen to have any prove/source for that? I mean no offense, but I am sceptical by nature.

Comment: about not using google maps app? i have no prove, just my personal knoledge and criteria

Comment: using an api is different from use the download contents of the app you are using the api. api is a group of libraries or packages to connect with the other application. pokemon go uses Google maps api to use google maps maps (redundant lol) but doesnt imply that checks if you have google maps in your device or the downloaded content

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a workaround. Start the game with GPS location turned off. When the game loads and you find yourself standing in a blank lake, turn the GPS back on. This is working for me! Yay!

Comment: I had the same problem as well and turning my GPS off and back on again fixed it as well. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and fixed it. The problem was that I had accidentally turned GPS off on my phone. Reactivating fixed the problem completely.